# Error Installing R Packages from Source in Mac OSX - "make" command not found

Tags: r, osx-lion

I am having an issue with R that I cannot seem to figure out how to fix.

When trying to install an R package from source, I am running into the following error:

> ```
> * installing *source* package ‘cthresh’ ...
> ** libs
> *** arch - i386
> sh: make: command not found
> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cthresh’
> * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/cthresh’
> ```

Which would lead you to think that I do not have a compiler installed or that that $PATH is not set.  Neither is true.  I have installed XCode and echo $PATH gives me:

```
echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/admn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/admn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/admn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Developer-3.2.5/usr/bin:/Users/admn/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Developer-3.2.5/usr/bin
```

So you can see that Developer shows up in /usr/bin

I have even made sure by:

> export PATH=${PATH}:/Developer-3.2.5/usr/bin

If I call 'make' in bash or sh:

> sh-3.2$ make make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. 
>   Stop.
>
> bash-3.2$ make make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. 
>   Stop.

The compilers are there:

> bash-3.2$ gcc i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: no input files
>
> bash-3.2$ g++ i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1: no input files

So what gives?  Why is R not able to 'make'? I'm really at a loss on this one and can't seem to find the answer anywhere!  My guess is that R is not looking for the right compiler or something, but I can't figure out how to check where it is looking and why it fails on 'make'

I am on a MacBook Pro in OSX Lion. Please help!

---EDIT----

Ok I've made some headway on this problem. Even though I had added

PATH=${PATH}:/Developer-3.2.5/usr/bin

to my bash/sh .profile I needed to add it to the .Renviron file as well. I found that file in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/etc/

But now I'm getting this error:

> - installing *source* package ‘cthresh’ ...
>     ** libs
>     *** arch - i386
>     make: *** No rule to make target `._cthreb.o', needed by`cthresh.so'.  Stop.
>     ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cthresh’

This makes me think there may be additional things to add to this .Renviron file?  Any ideas on what?

Comment: Ok I've made some headway on this problem.  Even though I had added PATH=${PATH}:/Developer-3.2.5/usr/bin to my bash/sh .profile I needed to add it to the .Renviron file.  I found that file in:  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/etc/

Comment: The mac faq for R might have some good tips, especially section 2.http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html

Comment: Post this to the r-sig-mac mailing list.  They will point you to faqs on setting up Lion to compile R packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to install "Command Line Tools" from preferences in Xcode 4 for Lion. Otherwise gcc is not available by just installing Xcode in Lion.

Comment: Note that you may also need to redo this after updating Xcode.